# Deep Cloning C++ class that inherits CCNode in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm stuck with something in Cocos2dx ...

When i copy my class that inherits CCNode, i get a shallow copy of my class but the base type seem to still point to the original node address. We dont seem to get a deep clone of any object that inherits CCNode, any ideas anyone?

Basically i have....

```
GameItem* pTemp = new GameItem(*_actualItem);

// loops through all the blocks in gameitem and updates their position 
pTemp->moveDown(); 

    // if in boundary or collision etc...
if (_gameBoard->isValidMove(pTemp))
{
    _actualItem = pTemp;

    // display the position
    CCLog("pos (1) --- (X : %d,Y : %d)",  _actualItem->getGridX(),_actualItem->getGridY());
}
```

Then doesn't work, because the gameitem inherits CCNode and has the collection of another class that also inherits CCNode with is a pointer.

its just creating a shallow copy and when you look at children of the gameitem node in the copy, it still just points to the original base type?

```
class GameItem : public CCNode {

// maps to the actual grid position of the shape
CCPoint* _rawPosition;
// tracks the current grid position
int _gridX, _gridY;
// tracks the change if the item has moved
CCPoint _offset;

public:
//constructors
GameItem& operator=(const GameItem& item);
GameItem(Shape shape);

}
```

then in the implementation....

```
GameItem& GameItem::operator=(const GameItem& item)
{
_gridX = item.getGridX();
_gridY = item.getGridY();
_offset = item.getOffSet();
_rawPosition = item.getRawPosition();

// how do i copy the node?

return *this;
}
```

Any ideas are welcome at this point!!

thanks

Comment: If there's any way to make the question more concise, you'll be far more likely to get an answer. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: yeah, it was a little long - my first thought was to give as much as possible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936348/cocos2d-how-to-clone-a-ccnode-hierarchy

Comment: Also: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/36953